# Send linux command between 2 pis on same network

Tags: ssh, apache-httpd

I was wondering if it was possible to control say RPB (Raspberry Pi B) from RPA,  using Linux commands.

The two PIs are on the same network 192.168.1.static-ip-address.

I log into both of them via SSH.

I have an Apache server on one of them,  which I can, via PHP, run linux commands on the machine that the server is on, from outside my network.

I wondered if I could send a Linux command via the same Apache  server to the other machine; or would it be better to install a separate server on the second machine?

Comment: Send a Linux command is a little vague.  Do you just want to execute an arbitrary command? If you just want to execute a command on the remote machine you could just use ssh, e.g. ssh paul@raspB 'ls -l' would execute ls -l on raspB as user paul.

Comment: I want to execute arbitrary command on pib from pia, from outside the local network. I hava an Apache server running on pia. I currently ssh in using my windows laptop, from inside the local network, but i want to run the command via a secure website, hosted on pia, but running the command on pib. Lets say the comnand is df-h as an example. I want to display the free space on pib on the website hosted on pia.

Comment: Have your PHP run the ssh command.  I wouldn't like to consider all the potential security holes though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can execute shell commands remotely using ssh.   `man ssh` has more info than you'll ever want -- here's the essential info:

Let's call the host on which you want the commands to run the target, and the host requesting it the client.

1. Generate a key using ssh-keygen on the client, using the account that will be making the requests.  Accept the default value for any prompts.
2. Copy the public key (default file name is ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub) to the target machine, and append to the file ~/.ssh/authorized_keys for the user that will run the commands.  You can do this via `cat id_rsa.pub >>~/.ssh/authorized_keys`
3. From the client, you should be able to run commands on the target with a command like

   ssh -l*user* *target*  *command*

where *user* is the username to use on the target (can be omitted if same user as the client)

*target* is the name or ip address of the target

*command* is the command to execute

An example with a user account jim on target host utilipi might be

```
ssh -ljim utilipi date
```

This will run the `date` command on utilipi and display the output on the client